# Access 2002 email all query records per vendor

Tags: ms-access

I have a vba that can send out multiple emails to vendors, but I would like to change it so it embeds the query and only sends one email per vendor.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Option Compare Database

Public Sub SendFollowUpEmail() 
    Dim db As DAO.Database 
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Dim emailTo As String 
Dim emailSubject As String 
Dim emailText As String

Dim outApp As Outlook.Application 
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem 
Dim outlookStarted As Boolean


On Error Resume Next 
Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0 
If outApp Is Nothing Then
    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    outlookStarted = True 
End If

Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "SELECT qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.kyUnique, qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Vendor Nbr],qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Vendor Name], " & _
                " qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Purchasing Document], qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.Item,qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Document Date], " & _
                " qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.Material, qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Short Text],qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Material Group], " & _
                " qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Invoice Sent], qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Order Quantity],qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Order Unit], " & _
                " qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Quantity in SKU], qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Stockkeeping unit],qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Net price], " & _
                " qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.Currency, qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Price Unit],qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Release status], " & _
                " qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[No of Positions], tblVendors.Vendor, tblVendors.Email " & _
                " FROM qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices LEFT JOIN tblVendors ON qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Vendor Nbr] =tblVendors.[Vendor Number] " & _
                " WHERE (((qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.Material) Is Null) AND ((qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.[Invoice Sent]) Is Null));"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset) 
Do Until rs.EOF

    emailTo = Trim(rs.Fields("Email").Value & "; tom.nguyen@flocorp.com;mike.huston@flocorp.com")

    emailSubject = "Open Invoices"
    
    emailText = Trim("Please send invoices of the below Purchase Orders:") & vbCrLf


    emailText = emailText & _
                "PO# " & rs.Fields("[Purchasing Document]").Value

    Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    outMail.To = emailTo
    outMail.Subject = emailSubject
    outMail.Body = emailText
    outMail.Send

    'rs.Edit
    'rs("FUP_Date_Sent") = Now()
    rs.MoveNext 
Loop

rs.Close 
Set rs = Nothing 
Set db = Nothing

If outlookStarted Then
    outApp.Quit 
End If

Set outMail = Nothing 
Set outApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to use two recordsets. The first selects the distinct vendors, and the second selects the invoices for that vendor. Something like:

```
Sub sSendFollowUpEMail()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsVendor As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsInvoice As DAO.Recordset
    Dim objOL As New Outlook.Application
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim emailTo As String
    Dim emailText As String
    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT V.[Vendor Number], V.EMail " _
        & " FROM qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices AS I LEFT JOIN tblVendors AS V ON I.[Vendor Nbr]=V.[Vendor Number] " _
        & " WHERE I.Material IS NULL " _
        & " AND I.[Invoice Sent] IS NULL;"
    Set rsVendor = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not (rsVendor.BOF And rsVendor.EOF) Then
        Do
            strSQL = "SELECT I.[Purchasing Document] " _
                & " FROM qry2002UnMatchedOpenInvoices AS I " _
                & " WHERE I.Material IS NULL " _
                & " AND I.[Invoice Sent] IS NULL " _
                & " AND I.[Vendor Nbr]=" & rsVendor("Vendor Number") _
                & " ORDER BY I.[Purchasing Document] ASC;"
            Set rsInvoice = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
            If Not (rsInvoice.BOF And rsInvoice.EOF) Then
                emailText = "Please pay:"
                Do
                    emailText = emailText & vbCrLf & rsInvoice("Purchasing Document")
                    rsInvoice.MoveNext
                Loop Until rsInvoice.EOF
            End If
            emailTo = rsVendor!EMail
            Set objMail = objOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            objMail.To = emailTo
            objMail.Subject = EmailSubject
            objMail.Body = emailText
            objMail.Send
            rsVendor.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsVendor.EOF
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsVendor.Close
    rsInvoice.Close
    Set rsVendor = Nothing
    Set rsInvoice = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
    objOL.Quit
    Set objOL = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbcrfl & "sSendFollowUpEMail", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

A few notes.

1. In your original recordset you were including a whole load of fields that were not used in this procedure, which is not recommended - only get data that you need as this will enhance performance;
2. Secondly, it appears that you are mixing early and late binding of Outlook;
3. Finally, I've used aliases for the query/table names in the SQL statements - this makes the SQL more manageable, and also if you need to change one of the original tables/queries it is a lot easier to change the name just once.

Regards,

Comment: When I try running this, I get a syntax error missing operator error.

Comment: There was a missing closing ] in the rsInvoice SQL statement. If that didn't work, please indicate where the error occurs.

Comment: That works almost perfect.  I also had to change the second "FROM qry2002UnMatchedOpenInvoices AS I" to qry002UnmatchedOpenInvoices.  OK, so that sends out the email, but if there is a PO with multiple open line items it will duplicate the purchasing document that many times.  How can I get it to only show one unique purchasing document?

Comment: Try using `SELECT DISTINCT I.[Purchasing Document]` as the start of the rsInvoice SQL statement.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That works great.  Now to use this to figure out how to do the same for Open Orders.  This provides me with a starting point to figure out.  Teach a man to fish...

Comment: Good - in that case please mark this as the answer.